# MVC2 without Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have a case where MVC's routing (mapping a url to a controller) is just getting in the way. I want to circumvent it and send all urls to a single controller (no matter the format and without any attempt to parse them).

I assumed this would be easy, but I'm stuck. 
Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you want to solve? Do you want to ignore the URL entirely? I'd almost say that from your question, you really don't want to use MVC for this problem.

Comment: how could you determine what action methods you are calling if you don't put a format or even without routing? you should atleast put 1 routing or replace the default routing in your routing table to obtain what you want.

Comment: I plan to parse the HttpRequest in the controller and then delegate sub-controllers. I need to do this because the full route can't be determined from the url alone; I need to look at info in the header.

How can i make a route which will send any url, regardless of content to a single controller&action?

Comment: I would suggest in this case writing your own Route Handler and replace or subclass the default one..

Comment: still you will have atleast 1 route in your routing table, you cannot achieve this without a route :)

Comment: Thanks Rob, I guess you're right (albeit anal). I would renamed the thread if I could find a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a catch-all route (global.asax) and define a default action/controller to this route..

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "All",
            "{*all}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to `Application_Start` in Global.asax.cs should work:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(null, "{*path}", new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" });
```

The parameter to `MyAction` should be called `path`.